# Boolean operation in Slick on tagged Boolean type

Tags: scala, slick

I have tagged types implemented as [here](http://www.edofic.com/posts/2015-05-02-tagged-types.html).

With them I tag all my model's attributes that are more or less generic (primitives, `String`, etc). When I use Slick for mapping models to the dabase I have them usually defined like this:

```
val isDeleted = column[Boolean @@ CompanyDeleted]("deleted", O.Default(false.tag))
```

while type mappers I define as:

```
implicit def taggedBooleanColumnType[U]: BaseColumnType[Boolean @@ U] =
  MappedColumnType.base[Boolean @@ U, Boolean](_.untag, _.tag[U])
```

It allows me to do all CRUD operations on model. However when I try to e.g.:

```
def fetchById(companyId: Long @@ CompanyId): SqlAction[Option[Company], NoStream, Read] =
companies.filter(c => c.companyId === companyId && !c.isDeleted).result.headOption
```

this would fail as `Rep[Boolean @@ CompanyDeleted]` is nethier `Rep[Boolean]` nor `Rep[Option[Boolean]]`. When I create implicits:

```
implicit def taggedBooleanExtensionMethods[P1, U](c: slick.lifted.Rep[P1]): TaggedBooleanExtensionMethods[P1, U] =
  new TaggedBooleanExtensionMethods[P1, U](c)

implicit def taggedBooleanColumnCanBeQueryCondition[U]: CanBeQueryCondition[slick.lifted.Rep[Boolean @@ U]] =
  new CanBeQueryCondition[slick.lifted.Rep[Boolean @@ U]] {
    def apply(value: slick.lifted.Rep[Boolean @@ U]) = value
  }

class TaggedBooleanExtensionMethods[P1, U](val c: Rep[P1])
    extends AnyVal
    with ExtensionMethods[Boolean @@ U, P1] {
  protected[this] implicit def b1Type = implicitly[TypedType[Boolean @@ U]]

  import slick.lifted.FunctionSymbolExtensionMethods._

  def &&[P2, R](b: Rep[P2])(implicit om: o#arg[Boolean @@ U, P2]#to[Boolean @@ U, R]) =
    om.column(Library.And, n, b.toNode)
  def ||[P2, R](b: Rep[P2])(implicit om: o#arg[Boolean @@ U, P2]#to[Boolean @@ U, R]) =
    om.column(Library.Or, n, b.toNode)
  def unary_! = Library.Not.column[P1](n)
}
```

I could `!_unary` operator, but not `&&` nor `||` (as the types of `Rep`s don't match).

My question is: can I provide/modify implicits to be able to perform boolean operations on those columns? I am especially interested in `||` as `&&` can be done using chained `filter`s.

Answer (score 1):

It is not the pretties solution, but it is the best I came up with:

```
implicit class TaggedBooleanAsFirstOperand[P1, U](val c: Rep[P1 @@ U]) {
  private val em = new BooleanColumnExtensionMethods[P1](c.untagM)
  type o = OptionMapperDSL.arg[Boolean, P1]

  def @&&[P2, R](b: Rep[P2])(implicit om: o#arg[Boolean, P2]#to[Boolean, R]): Rep[R] = em.&&[P2, R](b)
  def @||[P2, R](b: Rep[P2])(implicit om: o#arg[Boolean, P2]#to[Boolean, R]): Rep[R] = em.||[P2, R](b)
  def unary_! : Rep[P1] = em.unary_!
}

implicit class TaggedBooleanAsSecondOperand[P1](val c: Rep[P1]) {
  private val em = new BooleanColumnExtensionMethods[P1](c)
  type o = OptionMapperDSL.arg[Boolean, P1]

  def &&@[P2, U, R](b: Rep[P2 @@ U])(implicit om: o#arg[Boolean, P2]#to[Boolean, R]): Rep[R] = em.&&[P2, R](b.untagM)
  def ||@[P2, U, R](b: Rep[P2 @@ U])(implicit om: o#arg[Boolean, P2]#to[Boolean, R]): Rep[R] = em.||[P2, R](b.untagM)
}

implicit class TaggedBooleanAsBothOperands[P1, U](val c: Rep[P1 @@ U]) {
  private val em = new BooleanColumnExtensionMethods[P1](c.untagM)
  type o = OptionMapperDSL.arg[Boolean, P1]

  def @&&@[P2, V, R](b: Rep[P2 @@ V])(implicit om: o#arg[Boolean, P2]#to[Boolean, R]): Rep[R] = em.&&[P2, R](b.untagM)
  def @||@[P2, V, R](b: Rep[P2 @@ V])(implicit om: o#arg[Boolean, P2]#to[Boolean, R]): Rep[R] = em.||[P2, R](b.untagM)
}

implicit def taggedBooleanColumnCanBeQueryCondition[U]: CanBeQueryCondition[Rep[Boolean @@ U]] =
  new CanBeQueryCondition[Rep[Boolean @@ U]] {
    def apply(value: Rep[Boolean @@ U]) = value.untagM
  }
```

Basically, once a column with tagged value is used as a boolean expression, the result will be already untagged into something that Slick can work on. Due to (a wild guess) conflicting implicits I couldn't use name `&&` and `||` for all boolean operations, so I added `@` on the side, which has (still) tagged column.

E.g. for companies table defined as:

```
val companyId = column[Long @@ CompanyId]("companyid", O.AutoInc, O.PrimaryKey)
val isDeleted = column[Boolean @@ CompanyDeleted]("deleted", O.Default(false.tag))
```

I can:

```
val companyId = 1L.tag[CompanyId]
// fetch deleted companies
companies.filter(_.isDeleted).result
// fetch company by id if it is deleted
// c.isDeleted is tagged, so && it requires @ on right
companies.filter(c => c.companyId === companyId &&@ c.isDeleted).result.headOption
// fetch company by id if it is NOT deleted
// ! made c.isDeleted untagged so there is no need for additional @
companies.filter(c => c.companyId === companyId && !c.isDeleted).result.headOption
```

I would prefer to not have to add `@`, but at least I can do queries without putting `c.columnName.untagM` everywhere.